# IntelliJ - lambda expression { brace on the new line?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, lambda

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> formats code like this:

```
EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
}
```

I want it to be like this:

```
EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> 
{
}
```

Is there a way to achieve this? I tried: Settings, Editor, Code Style, Java, Wrapping and Braces, Braces placement and I have:

In class declaration: Next line 
In method declaration: Next line 
Other: Next line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can apply only for lambda expressions. Anyway you can try,

- Go to File -> Settings -> Editor -> Code Style -> Java
- Select '**Wrapping and Braces**' tab.
- Go to Braces Replacement -> Other
- Select ' Next Line, Next line if wrapped' as your preference.

[image]